# How to prove this implication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a matrix $n \times n$  and $b_1....b_k$ are $k$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Does anyone know how to prove the following implication

$Ab_1, ..., Ab_{k}$ is a spanning set of  $\mathbb{R}^{n} \Rightarrow  b_{1},...,b_{k}$ is a spanning set of  $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ .

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If $b_1,\dots, b_k$ do not span $\mathbb R^n$ then you can chose $m<n$ between them, say $b_1,\dots,b_m$ that span the same space $Span(b_1,\dots,b_k)$. Then
$Ab_1,\dots,Ab_m$ span the same space as $Ab_1,\dots,Ab_k$ which therefore has dimension at most $m<n$, hence their Span cannot be $\mathbb R^n$.

By the way, which are the theoretical tools that you can use for solving this problem?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am an undergraduate student.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer copied from stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030098)

In essence, this question is asking if $rank(A⋅B)=n$ implies $rank(B)=n$. This is a consequence of

$$rank(A\cdot B) \le \min( rank(A), rank(B) )$$

and the fact that for reasons of dimension of the spaces involved, $rank(A) \le n$ and $rank(B) \le \min(k, n)$, so that the combined chain

$$n = rank(A⋅B) \le  min( rank(A), rank(B) ) \le min(k, n)$$

leaves not much wiggle space.

---

On a more elementary level: You want to show that any vector $c$ can be obtained as (possibly non-unique) linear combination of the vectors $b_1,...,b_k$. Per assumption, $Ac$ can be combined using the spanning set $Ab_1,...,Ab_k$. Now explore what the equation
$$
A(c-\sum λ_kb_k)=0
$$
implies. It still is not trivial, somewhere you have to use the dimension formula.

Comment: Ok thanks, the notion of rank is new for me... I hope to learn it soon with my teacher.